# Why passing function object to Object.keys() returns empty array?

Tags: javascript, function

So, functions in js are objects with some keys, right? I'm trying to iterate through them, but i'm getting empty list:

```
function f(a) {
console.log(Object.keys(f)) //prints []
console.log(f.arguments) //key "arguments" exists and prints Arguments object
}
```

Any expanation why Object.keys() doesn't return keys for function object?

Comment: Btw, `f.arguments` should not exist, it's deprecated and accessing it in strict mode will throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` will only list *enumerable* properties. The `arguments` property is not enumerable, as you can see if you use `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

The property exists, but

```js
function f() {

}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(f, 'arguments'));
```

To get a list of all own-property keys (excluding symbols), including non-enumerable ones, you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

```js
function f() {

}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(f));
```

which, here, gives you

```
[
  "length",
  "name",
  "arguments",
  "caller",
  "prototype"
]
```

`Object.keys` could have returned properties if any properties put directly on the function were enumerable, such as

```js
function f() {

}
f.someProp = 'foo';
console.log(Object.keys(f));
```